# Counting customized tags in csv file

Tags: python, count, tags

I have a csv file with sentences and I want to tag some words in each sentence and then count how many this tag occuers in each sentence.
How can I do that using python?
For example:
I have this sentence "I like Apple and Mango. Also, I prefer Tomato and Onion"
So, I need to tag apple and Mango as fruit and then count the tag (fruit) = 2, also, for Onion and Tomato I need to tag them as (vegtable) and count tag (vegtable)= 2

I could not do that

Comment: Try normalising the sentence first by removing all the punctuation and making all characters lowercase

Comment: Then what's your idea for the tags ?

Comment: I already extracted user reviews into CSV file and preprocessed data. After that, I want to tag security keywords and then count them (how many time this tag appear in one review)